# Express promise throw error

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, promise

I am using Express with denodeify module. I`m getting error when i try to render email template asynchronously.

```
.then(function () {
     return denodeify(res.render)(path.resolve('verify-email'), {
         name: user.displayName,
         appName: config.app.title,
         mail: user.email,
         url: 'http://' + req.headers.host
     });
})
.then(function (emailHTML) {
     // code which is not executed
})
.catch(function (err) {
     // [TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined]
});
```

I tryed use res.render without callback and it worked fine, but i need to output email template in variable.
Also i cant understand how i can debug this part of code. Thanks for help!
Whole code

```
function sendVerificationEmail(user, req, res) {
    return denodeify(crypto.randomBytes)(20)
        .then(function (buffer) {
            user.verificationToken = buffer.toString('hex');
            return user.save();
        })
        .then(function () {
            user.password = undefined;
            user.salt = undefined;
            delete req.session.redirect_to;

            return denodeify(res.render)(path.resolve('modules/users/server/templates/verify-email'), {
                name: user.displayName,
                appName: config.app.title,
                mail: user.email,
                url: 'http://' + req.headers.host + '/api/auth/verify/' + user.verificationToken + "/" + user.email
            });
        })
        .then(function (emailHTML) {
            const mailOptions = {
                to: user.email,
                from: config.mailer.from,
                subject: 'Verify Email',
                html: emailHTML
            };
            return denodeify(smtpTransport.sendMail)(mailOptions);
        });
}

exports.updateAuthData = function (req, res, next) {
    const userId = req.session.userId;
    delete req.session.userId;

    if (!userId) {
        return res.status(401).send({
            message: 'No active session'
        });
    }

    let user;

    User.findById(userId)
        .then()
        .then((_user) => {
            user = _user;

            const fields = Object.keys(req.body);
            const neededFields = user.getMissingAuthFields();
            const missingFields = _.difference(fields, neededFields);

            if (missingFields.length !== 0) {
                throw new CustomError('Missing fields: ' + missingFields.join(', '))
            }

            for (let field of User.requiredAuthorizationFields) {
                if (!!user[field]) {
                    throw new CustomError('User already has ' + field);
                }
            }

            User.requiredAuthorizationFields.forEach((field) => user[field] = req.body[field]);

            return true;
        })
        .then(function () {
            return sendVerificationEmail(user, req, res);
        })
        .then(() => {
            res.send({
                message: 'An email has been sent to the provided email, please verify your account.'
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            res.status(400).send({
                message: 'Failure sending email'
            });
        })
};
```

Comment: As the error says: `req` is undefined. From where do you require this variable?

Comment: You can do this without Promises, `res.render('verify-email',{name:....}, function(err,emailHTML){ res.render('index',{ email: emailHTML }) }); `

Comment: Please add the whole function.

Comment: Error displays that there is some object which must have a .req property and that object is undefined, so I can't understand what kind of object is that..

Comment: @Michelem its a large function and error occurred exactly at that .then block

Comment: @Molda i know, but i have to use promises.

Comment: @Michelem I added whole code

Comment: The error does not come from the code posted - the error clearly suggests that the error is with a piece of code that tried to access `.req` on a variable that is undefined ... somewhere in the code you haven't posted there's a *something*.**req** ... surely you can get a better error dump from nodejs than just the message, you should be able to get a file, line number and stack trace

Comment: @styopdev: `res.render` is not an asynchronous function, so it doesn't make sense to use promises for it.

Comment: @Bergi res.render receive 3-th additional param callback http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, we have to bind "this" variable like this

```
 return denodeify(res.render.bind(res))(path.resolve('modules/users/server/templates/verify-email'), {
      name: user.displayName,
      appName: config.app.title,
      mail: user.email,
      url: 'http://' + req.headers.host + '/api/auth/verify/' + user.verificationToken + "/" + user.email
 });
```

The reason of error was the following code in express "res.render" function

```
  var app = this.req.app;
  var done = callback;
  var opts = options || {};
  var req = this.req;
  var self = this;
```

the right way is to use:

`denodeify(res.render.bind(res))(path, options)`

instead of

```
denodeify(res.render)(path, options)
```

Thanks to all for replies!